# Getting org.postgresql.util.psqlexception: unknown types value when performing migration from SQL Server to Postgres DB

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, exception, migration

I am getting the following exception `org.PostgreSQL.util.psqlexception: unknown types` when migrating data from SQL Server to Postgres. Currently, I'm performing the migration using a tool called DBCrane. Any ideas as to what can cause this?

The tables I'm migrating have datatypes like nvarchar(255), datetime, bit, and bigint. The tables from the source (SQL Server) to the destination DB (Postgres) have the following mapping of datatypes:

1. nvarchar(255) -> varchar(255) or Text
2. datetime -> timestamp
3. bigint -> bigint
4. bit -> boolean

Comment: Well `nvarchar` columns are Unicode UCS-2 encoded by default, or UTF-16 when the containing database uses a Supplementary Character collation. Perhaps you're overflowing the range of characters allowed in `varchar` columns?

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, I was playing around and also tried `text` data type in Postgres to map with `nvarchar`, it's still not working. What do you suggest? would there be any way to tell whether the `nvarchar` columns are Unicode USC-2 or UTF-16, then afterward change the Postgres datatype to match that? Thanks